# CSS dropdown problems in IE

Tags: jquery, css

Ok, I have tried a number of solutions, including inserting a hover class with jquery, csshover3.htc, straight javascript, adding a specific width to my dropdown li's, adding a border around my ul's and li's to force hasLayout.  I have [this menu here](http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/lodgings/houses):  it works beautifully in everything but IE.  IE8 and IE9, it works about half the time.  IE7, not so much (it works sometimes if you keep mousing over the li with a dropdown).  Here is my CSS:

```
nav {
display:inline;
position:relative;
left:200px;
z-index:10;
}


nav li{ float:left;}    
nav li a{
display:block;
background:#0099ff;
margin:1px;
padding:4px;
color:#000066;
border:1px solid #0099FF;
border-radius:5px 5px 0px 0px;
position:relative;
behavior:url(http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/app/webroot/js/PIE.htc);
text-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(255,255,255,1);
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
 -webkit-box-shadow:1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,102,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow:1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,102,0.5);
 box-shadow:1px -1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,102,0.5);

}



nav li a:hover {
color:#00FFFF;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgba(0,153,255,1);
background-image:linear-gradient(#66CCFF 0%, #0099FF 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(#66CCFF 0%, #0099FF 100%);
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(#66CCFF 0%, #0099FF 100%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(#66CCFF 0%, #0099FF 100%);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#0099FF),    to(#66CCFF));
filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#66CCFF', endColorstr='#0099FF')";
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr='#66CCFF', endColorstr='#0099FF')";
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
-o-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
transition:all 0.3s ease-out;

}



nav li ul {
display:none;
width:200px;
}

nav li:hover ul, nav li.hover ul{
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;

}

nav li:hover li, nav li.hover li {
float:none;
display:block;
text-align:left;
}

nav li:hover li a {
margin:0;
border-radius:0px;
behavior: url(http://rentcondos4less.cloudmedia.biz/app/webroot/js/PIE.htc);
position:relative;
 box-shadow:none;
 border-bottom:1px dashed #000066;

}
```

Margins and padding have been reset to 0 higher up in the css file.  I need the menu to be spaced evenly apart, not just centered horizontally, and the dropdown li's really do look better if I let the dropdown ul's choose their width based on the width of the largest of their children.  So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have a margin in IE7 that causes you to mouse out of the anchor and thus the menu closing.

Try using http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

I've run into this problem on http://thecl.com and this was a great solution.

Comment: Beautiful site!  Question:  Can you tell me which margin in particular is doing this?  Perhaps this is the same reason IE8 and IE9 are so hit and miss with the dropdowns as well.  I have seen hoverIntent and am planning to implement it in the morning.